# Preclude Android from interrupting user input / taking off focus from EditText element

Tags: android

I'm implementing a search mechanism using popups(PopupWindow) and a plain EditText element. The problem is that as long as user types the search sequence, popups suggesting the results may arise and then the EditText element loses it's focus.

I need somehow to sustain EditText focused during user input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to implement something that already exists in android. It's called `AutoCompleteTextView`. Just [use the native one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).